# What is the app that has a logo like 'p' inside a square?

Tags: applications

Where is this app logo that looks like 'p' inside a square come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's the [Peel Smart Remote](https://peel.freshdesk.com/support/home) old logo. Peel make your compatible android phone as a remote controller for various devices, such as televisions, set top boxes, digital video recorders (DVRs) and other devices.

It allows users to tune in directly to a TV show or movie, record the show on their DVR, set up a calendar reminder or share with contacts by clicking a promotional banner.

[image: Old logo]

[image: New logo]

Learn more about  [Peel Technologies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peel_Technologies)